# Oracle Forms Migrations To Oracle APEX 5.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Since Oracle APEX 5.1 there's no way to create an application based on the migration project. The button that they referred on the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39148/appmgr_forms.htm#AEMIG248) doesn't appear in the new version:

> On Application Migrations page, click the project name. 
> Click
>   Create Application. 
> The Generate Application wizard appears.

[image: Application Migration Page]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's correct, that functionality has been desupported with APEX 5.1 - as outlined in our APEX 5.1. Release Notes, section 1.7.1 "Desupport of Migration Project Functionality":

https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMRN/toc.htm#HTMRN-GUID-8F584DDA-46F4-4382-BDE9-DB7DD0BAC18E

Your best option is to utilise the Migration Project to analyze your Oracle Forms application, and the use the Create Application Wizard to generate a new application on the underlying database objects.

Regards,
Hilary
Oracle Application Express Development Team

Comment: Well You right, Doc refer to "no longer supports the migration of Microsoft Access applications" and In addition, you can no longer generate an application directly from a Migration Project..

Comment: I agree with @Hilary, it's best one-way for migration.